# how to find commit id by commited text in git log?

Tags: git

I have some block of code commited to a repo a long long time ago.
I need to find the commit id, but I don't even remember neither commit's title not its author.

Is there any way to find the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the line number git log or git blame will tell you all the edits for a given line and the commit id when used like this:

```
git log -L <start line>,<end line>:<filename>
```

or

```
git blame -L <start line>,<end line> filename
```

Alternately, if you know the contents of the edit, you can use `git blame` and a regular expression as detailed here:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame